# Webservice and Database for Mobile Access

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, json

i want to create database and a webservice for mobile computing. The database should be generic which means iOS and Android can easily access to it.
Therefore i tried some stuff with php webservice JSON and mysql db. But i think a more professional environment would be a Java JAX Restful Service. Does a JAX Webserive need an application server like tomcat ? Is iOS compatible to a JAX Restful Service (I think yes cause the API is JSON) ?

Or is just php mysql json a valid solution ?
Would be nice if someone who already did such a project some information.

Greetz

Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for JAX, you would use something like Jersey and Tomcat. JAX is built on the Servlet model. iOS/Android would be compatible since you are only serving a RESTful service via JAX over something like JSON. It would look no different than a PHP RESTful server (outside of maybe the Server Header).

When choosing language/framework, there is never one true answer. Of course it's always a business reason, do people already know java. Will there be a large amount of developers working on the project, is type safety important, etc.

Some info:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

Answer (score 1):

Well our API as example is developed with Java (Spring) and runs on a TomCat (configured for multi threading). It's connected to a MySQL database using Hibernate as ORM. Installed on a server with average hardware it handles 200 requets per second ...

Websites and apps are using it and it works quite well.

Comment: Hey Ben, that setup is exactly im looking for. Ok, now it is more clear for me (java webservice on tomcat) - nice to hear it works great. Thx for your info !